# IMDbPY handling None object

Tags: python, imdbpy

I'm trying to pull data about cinematographers from IMDbPY and i'm encountering a null object. I'm not sure how to deal with that None object in the code. Could someone help me out please?

here's where I have reached.

```
from imdb import IMDb, IMDbError
ia = IMDb() 
itemdop = ''
doplist = []


items = ["0050083", "6273736", "2582802"]

def imdblistdop(myList=[], *args):
    for x in myList:
      movie = ia.get_movie(x)
      cinematographer = movie.get('cinematographers')[0]
      cinematographer2 = movie.get('cinematographers')
      print(cinematographer)
      print(doplist)
      try:
            itemdop = cinematographer['name']
            doplist.append(itemdop)
      except KeyError as ke:
            print('Nope!')


imdblistdop(items)
```

The code is not working at all and all i get is this:

> Boris Kaufman
> []

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
21
22
---> 23 imdblistdop(items)
24
25

in imdblistdop(myList, *args)
10     for x in myList:
11       movie = ia.get_movie(x)
---> 12       cinematographer = movie.get('cinematographers')[0]
13       cinematographer2 = movie.get('cinematographers')
14       print(cinematographer)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

`cinematographer` is a list. It means that you can point to an an entry in the list using its index. Example: `cinematographer[2]`. You can **not** use a string to point to an entry in the list.

Comment: Bro there was an error in my code. while editing it for here, i messed up.

Comment: it parses the first filmid then goes belly up

Comment: There's an error in the way that i'm trying to handle the error?

Comment: before `cinematographer = movie.get('cinematographers')[0]` add the line `print(movie.get('cinematographers'))` - what do you get?

Comment: [<Person id:0442100[http] name:_Boris Kaufman_>]
Boris Kaufman
[<Person id:0442100[http] name:_Boris Kaufman_>]
[]
None
<ipython-input-22-fabda4f43123> in imdblistdop(myList, *args)
     11       movie = ia.get_movie(x)
     12       print(movie.get('cinematographers'))
---> 13       cinematographer = movie.get('cinematographers')[0]
     14       cinematographer2 = movie.get('cinematographers')
     15       print(cinematographer)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What is the output of the `print`? put rest of the code in comment

Comment: dont point to external resources. Just follow what I have asked you to do.

Comment: or this one?
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-YOKCOG0vCd6ZXAgDf2EXm2TBzAMRxWp?usp=sharing

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable